# Problem based on proving equal triangles in area

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. If $O$ be any point on $BD$ then prove that $$\triangle OAB=\triangle OAD+\triangle OAC$$[image]

My Attempt 
$$\triangle ADB=\triangle BDC$$
$$\triangle OAM=\triangle OMC$$

Now, please help me to move further..

Comment: **Hint.** It's only true if O lies on DM, not if it lies on MB. If you subtract OAM from both sides, this is the same as claiming that the area of BAM is the areas of OAD plus OMC. Also, BAM is similar to DCM ...

Comment: As in the figure, O is in DM

Comment: is it a parallelogram , or a rhombus ?

Comment: It's a parallelogram

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have proved that $$\triangle OAM=\triangle OMC$$

Now note that $\overline{DO}+\overline{OM}=\overline {MB}$ so that :
$$
\triangle OAD+\triangle OAM=\triangle AMB
$$
because the triangles have the same height, and
$$
\triangle AOB=\triangle AOM+\triangle AMD
$$

---

$$
\triangle OAB=\triangle OAM+ \triangle MAB= \triangle OAM+\triangle OAM+ \triangle OAD=$$ $$= \triangle OAM+\triangle OMC+\triangle OAD=\triangle OAC+\triangle OAD
$$

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me. Could you please explain?

Comment: I've added to may answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\triangle{OAD}=\triangle{OCD}$$
and
$$\triangle{MCD}=\triangle{MAB}$$

So, 
$$\triangle{OAD}+\triangle{OAC}=\triangle{OCD}+\triangle{OAC}=\triangle{MCD}+\triangle{OAM}=\cdots$$

Comment: But how it works?

Comment: @user335710: I added some details. Take a look.

Comment: How do you get the second statement?

Comment: @user335710: $\triangle{OCD}+\triangle{OAC}=\triangle{OCD}+\triangle{OCM}+\triangle{OAM}$ $=\triangle{MCD}+\triangle{OAM}$. I hope this helps.

Comment: .......Yeah....

Answer (score 0):

$$\triangle OAB=\triangle OAD+\triangle OAC$$

Means that

$$\triangle OAM + \triangle AMB = \triangle OAD+\triangle OAM + \triangle MOC$$

Means that

$$\triangle AMB = \triangle OAD+ \triangle MOC$$

But wait, $\triangle MOC = \triangle OAM$!

Observing that the line segment $\overline{AM}$ bisects $\triangle DAB$...

Can you finish?

Comment: How do you get the first statement?

Comment: @user335710 the first statement before the "means that" is what we are trying to prove. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I will use the following notation $[\text{Figure}]$ for the area of the figure. Such as $[XYZ]$ denotes the area of $\triangle XYZ$.

Note that $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle CDB$ are congruent, thus their areas are also equal, but since they share a common base $BD,$ the length of their altitudes $AQ$ and $CP$ must be equal for the areas of the triangles to be equal.

[image: Diagram 1]

Thus we know that $\triangle AOD$ and $\triangle COD,$ which have the same base $OD$ are equal heights $AQ=CP,$ must have the same area. Thus, we have;
$$[OAD]=[OCD]$$
$$\implies [OAD]+[OAC]=[OCD]+[OAC]=[OACD].$$

Hence, the right hand side of the desired equation is the area of the quadrilateral $OACD.$

[image: Diagram 2]

But quadrilateral $OACD$ can be bisected into $\triangle MCD$ and $\triangle OAM,$ so we have;
$$[OAD]+[OAC]=[OACD]=[MCD]+[OAM].$$

Since $\triangle MCD$ and $\triangle MAB$ are congruent, we know that $[MCD]=[MAB],$ and we have;
$$[OAD]+[OAC]=[MAB]+[OAM]=[OAB].$$

This is what was required.

Comment: The diagram looks neat, what did you use to create it?

Answer (score -1):

Completing $AOC$ to a parallelogram centered at $M$, the diagram becomes a proof by dissection of the stated formula.

The line segments in the completed diagram divide $OAB$ into $3$ pieces that can be assembled into the other two triangles.

For the formula to hold for all positions of $O$ the areas should be taken with $\pm$ signs according to the orientation of the triangles.

Comment: Actually one of the pieces of the dissection is only of equal-area, but is not congruent, to OAB, so this argument proves the formula but not through a true isometric dissection.   Eventually the proof uses the fact that area OAD = OAC which makes it the same idea as earlier answers.  If that is what the downvote was about, thanks to the voter for calling my attention to this.